# My Unity game behaves differently after uploading to Google Play... Is there any way to debug it?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

First of all, a disclaimer: I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to any kind of online functionality and distribution, and my coding skills aren't particularly advanced either (my game was scripted with a visual node-based scripting tool).

**My problem is this: my Unity game works just fine when I build and run it locally. But when I upload the exact same APK to Google Play (alpha branch) then download it through Google Play, it behaves differently.**

I first load into an 'initialisation' scene which sets up a lot of game variables, and also signs into Google Play Games. It should then load into the 'title' scene where the game begins.

When I'm running the Google Play build, the game just hangs in the 'initialisation' scene and never loads the 'title' scene.

**As far as I'm aware, there is no way to debug an app that's been downloaded from Google Play (even if it's just an alpha test build), but the problem is not reproducible in any local debug builds I make. So how can I find out what's going wrong and resolve the issue?**

Please make any steps understandable for an idiot beginner :) Thank you!

Comment: For anyone experiencing a similar issue: the problem was that I had "Split Application Binary" enabled in my build settings.

This should only be used for apps over 50MB, when you want to install a small 'loader' app first and then use that to download a larger package containing the rest of your game.